# Javascript Page reroute

Tags: javascript, redirect, cookies, web

We are making a chat web app using JavaScript  where we store the user session in a cookie. One of our pages requires a user to enter in his or her username and then press Go to be redirected to a chat room. The store values function is  being called by a button. It in turn calls the SetCookie funtion, which calls the redirect. However our button does not redirect them to the next page.

```
function setCookie(name, value){
        document.cookie=name + "=" + escape(value) + ", path=/; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
        console.log(document.cookie+"hello");
        var url = "file:///C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Mathworks/Lobby.html";    
        window.location.replace("file:///C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Mathworks/Lobby.html");
    }
    console.log(document.cookie);
    //this should set the UserName cookie to the proper value;
    function storeValues(form)
    {
        setCookie("userName", document.getElementById("inputBox").value);
        console.log(document.cookie+"word");
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is `document.location.replace()`, not `window.location.replace()`. You could also try `document.location.assign(url)`.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. Worked for me.

Comment: I copied your code, ran it through the debugger, and it is having a problem  with the first line of your `setCookie()` function. **Expiry is not defined.** Fix that and see if that works